# Mocking Local Method Inside of a Service Class in Mockito Spring Boot Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Autowired
    SomeOtherService otherService;    

    @Override
    public List<Something> getSomething(Integer id) {
        Something s = otherService.getOfSomething(id)
        return doSomething(s.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Something> doSomething(Integer id) {
        List<Something> list = new ArrayList<>();
        // --- Some Logic ---
        return list;
    }
}
```

I have a Service Class with the simpler structure as above. I've been figuring out how to mock a method that is present in the same service class whose method I am unit testing (that is how to mock doSomething() method while unit testing getSomething). Can someone please help me with mocking a method local to the service method I am unit testing? Thank you

My test Look as follows now

```
@Mock
SomeOtherService otherService;

@InjectMock
MyServiceImpl myServiceImpl;

@Test
public void testGetSomething() {
    Something s = new Something();
    when(otherService.getOfSomething(anyInt())).thenReturn(s);
    List<Something> list = myServiceImpl.getSomething(10);
    verify(otherService, times(1)).getOfSomething(anyInt());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want you could use a [Spy](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13). Basically you'll wrap your original service object and mock only the `doSomething` method.

However, a superior approach IMHO would be to design for testability: just extract the `doSomething` method into a separate class.